# How to index a Python list

Tags: python

```
list=[1,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,1,0,1,3,0,3,0,3,1]
```

so now i want to know if the 5th object in this list is 3:

```
if list.index(3)==5:
  print("yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

-> answer is "no"...
but it is, as you see.
So how can i solve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python 3, but I have to feel that   
else:   
  no   
is not valid.

Comment: @Hoopdady -- That depends on whether `no` is in the local namespace :P -- e.g. if `no = "Hello World"` before getting here, it would work on python2 or python3

Comment: @mglison -- fair.... I guess I should have said useful instead of valid

Comment: _" i want to know if the 5th object in this list is 3"_ : ``print list[5-1]==3`` and the mass is over. The -1 is due to the fact that first element is indexed 0.

Comment: If you absolutely want to print YES or NO : ``print ('NO','YES')[list[4]==3]``. Or ``print 'YES' if list[4]==3 else 'NO'``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. don't use `list` as a variable name. It masks one very useful command.
2. `index` is a list's method returning the position of a given element within a list. You want the opposite: get the element for a given position.

This code will help you. It checks whether the 5th (position 4) element of a list is 3:

```
lst = [1,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3,1,0,1,3,0,3,0,3,1]
if lst[4] == 3:
    print('yes')
```

Your code `list.index(3)` returns `1`, because the first occurence of `3` is at the position 1.

Comment: I think you mean `if lst[4] == 3`